# How to use webpack's raw-loader/ to-string-loader to convert css to string?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I use webpack5 and with below webpack configuration, it gets me one liner css exported to dist/main.css. I would like to take that css then convert it to string to use them in my tsx file. So I found two ways. One way is to use inline loader using raw-loader so I coded it like this in tsx file `import styleAsString from '!!raw-loader!../dist/main.css';` but I get "cannot find module or its corresponding type error". Then I found out about this loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-string-loader, which look simple to use. So in webpack.config.js, I type in `let output = require('./my.scss');` then I run `npm run build`, but I get build error saying cannot find my sass file. I'm new to webpack and I'm not sure what I need to do to get css as string. So something like this `'.puma{color:"black";}.raptors{font-size:12px;}'` What am I doing wrong?

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    theme: "./src/index.ts",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 

          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              import: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          // 'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              import: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              implementation: require("sass"),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "./fonts/[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".scss"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: {
      name: "[name]",
      type: "umd",
    },
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "main.css",
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
    minimize: true,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Replacing Inline Loader Syntax](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#replacing-inline-loader-syntax)

> It is now recommended to remove all inline loader syntax and use a `resourceQuery` condition to mimic the functionality of the inline syntax.

And use `asset/source`

> `asset/source`: exports the source code of the asset. Previously achievable by using `raw-loader`.

`my.css`:

```css
.puma {
    color: 'black';
}
.raptors {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

`index.js`:

```js
import mycss from './my.css?raw';

console.log(mycss, typeof mycss);
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                resourceQuery: /raw/,
                type: 'asset/source',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset main.js 114 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: main)
orphan modules 70 bytes [orphan] 1 module
./src/index.js + 1 modules 139 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 147 ms
```

Output

`dist/index.js`:

```js
(() => {
    'use strict';
    console.log(".puma {\n\tcolor: 'black';\n}\n.raptors {\n\tfont-size: 12px;\n}\n", 'string');
})();
```